# Why Is It Necessary to tell Expression where it is the file system and why more than once?

Tags: config

Don't say it's for flexibility!  If flexibility is all that matters, where is software for making a whole website by typing everything freeform all into one field.

So we draw lines, make judgments, to make the system practical.

I AM MOVING AN EE SITE NOW
Right now I am moving an ee site I have moved a few times, and every time, it is a super pain the butt.

I am going to give an example, below, of how EE handles a new path to where it runs, then how another system does it.  I pray no one will defend the dumb way EE has this setup.  I pray also the mastermind of this scheme, come forward, admit the problem, apologize, promise to fix it, and then fix it.

EXPRESSION ENGINE SETUP
[image]

ANOTHER SYSTEM
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are probably not going to get the answer you are looking for and I have no idea why EllisLab chose to do what they did when building EE as I am not part of their team. Having said that I recommend you email them and ask them personally.

But to answer your main issue of changing paths and urls easily. EllisLab has setup EE to handle a bunch of configuration details via the config.php file in your system folder. More documentation for those can be found in their [user guide](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html). While not shipped with EE there are many great tools to help you with this [Focus Lab Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) is a free option that I use as a base for every site I work on, and allows easy migrations. I move at least a site or two a week for people and after the 15-20 minutes it takes to make sure everything is configured I can do a complete server move in under 5 minutes.

Comment: Justin, thanks for sharing all that, great tip.